# Controlling arc axis with Vector3.Slerp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lerp

I'm using `Vector3.Lerp()` to instantiate some prefabs at a set distance from each other.  This works, but I've just started playing with `Vector3.Slerp`.

This creates a nice arc, however I'd like the arc to happen on either the X or Z axis, not the Y.  So rather than arcing up into the air, the prefabs remain in contact with the ground at all times.

I've been reading up on `euler local transforms` however I'm not entirely sure if that's the right thing.

If anyone could offer some advice, or input, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is using [RotateAround()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) an option for you instead?

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a little tinkering (and can't claim to fully understand the reasoning as of now, or whether this is the only solution) but it seems as long as the y-component of the start and end input Slerp Vectors are zero, the object will only travel in the xz plane. Below is an example:

```
Vector3 startpos;
Vector3 endpos;
Vector3 yoffset;
float t;

void Start() 
{
    startpos = new Vector3(-5, 2, 0);
    endpos = new Vector3(3, 2, 2);
    yoffset = new Vector3(0, 2, 0);
}


void Update()
{
    t = (t+Time.deltaTime);
    transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(startpos - yoffset, endpos - yoffset, t/5f);
    transform.position += yoffset;
}
```

Comment: You know what, I'm not entirely sure how that works either, but it does.  Thanks!  I was hoping that the Slerp just  had an overload somewhere to control it, but this seems to do the job.  I'll have a play with it some more.

Comment: I think this is because slerp isn't treating the start and end vector3 as points and interpolating between them - it's treating them as vectors and interpolating the angle and magnitude of them. If you have your vectors with zero y component then any angle interpolation between them will always be on the xz plane. If not, no guarantee, even if the y components of start and end are the same.